# Netlogo: How can send agents from "area x" to "area y" using an O/D matrix?

Tags: matrix, netlogo

I have a O/D matrix that might be useful to move people from one place to another. With the matrix extension, I attempt to build a simple model before I progress to the actual model, but ended up coding verbosely.

```
extensions  [matrix]
globals     [mat]
patches-own [location]
turtles-own [residency]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks

  ask patches [
    if pxcor >= 0 and pycor >= 0 [set pcolor black + 0 set location "ne" ]
    if pxcor <  0 and pycor >= 0 [set pcolor black + 1 set location "nw" ]
    if pxcor <  0 and pycor <  0 [set pcolor black + 2 set location "sw" ]
    if pxcor >= 0 and pycor <  0 [set pcolor black + 3 set location "se" ]
  ]

  ask n-of 40 patches [
   sprout 1 [
    set shape "person student"
    set heading random 360
    set residency [location] of patch-here
    if residency = "nw" [set color yellow + 2]
  ]
]


set-matrix
end

to set-matrix
  set mat matrix:from-row-list [[0.5 0.3 0.1 0.1][0.3 0.5 0.1 0.1][0.1 0.1 0.5 0.2][0.1 0.1 0.2 0.5]]
  print matrix:pretty-print-text mat
  ;pretty text print looks something like this
  ;    nw  ne  sw  se
  ;nw 0.5 0.3 0.1 0.1
  ;ne 0.3 0.5 0.1 0.1
  ;sw 0.1 0.1 0.5 0.2
  ;se 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.5
end


to go
ifelse(ticks mod 240 <= 120)[move-out][come-home]
tick
end

to move-out
  ;; North West Residents
  let n-of-nw count turtles with [residency = "nw"]
  let %nw-nw matrix:get mat 0 0
  let %nw-ne matrix:get mat 0 1
  let %nw-sw matrix:get mat 0 2
  let %nw-se matrix:get mat 0 3
  ask n-of (%nw-nw * n-of-nw) turtles with [residency = "nw"]
           [rt 45 lt 45 set heading random 360 fd 2
            face min-one-of patches with [location = "nw"][distance myself]]
  ask n-of (%nw-ne * n-of-nw) turtles with [residency = "nw"]
           [ifelse location = "ne"[face min-one-of patches with [location != "nw" and location = "ne"][distance myself]
             rt 45 lt 45 set heading random 360 fd 2]
            [rt 45 lt 45 set heading random 360 fd 2]]
  ask n-of (%nw-sw * n-of-nw) turtles with [residency = "nw"]
           [ifelse location = "sw"[face min-one-of patches with [location != "nw" and location = "sw"][distance myself]
             rt 45 lt 45 set heading random 360 fd 2]
            [rt 45 lt 45 set heading random 360 fd 2]]
  ask n-of (%nw-se * n-of-nw) turtles with [residency = "nw"]
           [ifelse location = "se"[face min-one-of patches with [location != "nw" and location = "se"][distance myself]
             rt 45 lt 45 set heading random 360 fd 2]
            [rt 45 lt 45 set heading random 360 fd 2]]


  ask turtles with [residency != "nw"][rt 45 lt 45 set heading random 360 fd 1]


end

to come-home
  ask turtles with [residency = "nw"]
      [ifelse location != "nw" [face min-one-of patches with [location = "nw"][distance myself] fd 1]
      [move-to one-of neighbors with [location = "nw"]]]

  ask turtles with [residency != "nw"][rt 45 lt 45 set heading random 360 fd 1]
end
```

Inside the Netlogo world, four regions splitted up at each corner as `northwest(nw), northeast(ne), southwest(sw), southeast(se)`. I created agents in a random space and assigned their `residency` according to their `location`. Then, I wrote a origin-destination matrix as below,

```
          nw  ne  sw  se
      nw 0.5 0.3 0.1 0.1
      ne 0.3 0.5 0.1 0.1
      sw 0.1 0.1 0.5 0.2
      se 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.5
```

where, for example, 30% of `nw` residents should move to `ne`. I only coded one region, but can anyone give comments to improve my code more sound? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a comment on the matrix approach, but on your overall design. The way you have it set up, your students will pick a new direction to head each tick. I am not sure that's what you intend. From your description it seems more likely that you want them to pick a destination once and then each tick move toward it (or head home). In that case, you want an extra turtles-own attribute for their destination and assign it during the setup.

Comment: There's also a whole bunch of changing directions that doesn't make a lot of sense - you have them turn left then turn right then pick a random direction before moving forward. So the left and right turns don't do anything, and the eventual movement has nothing to do with where they are going. Presumably you want them to pick a heading that is in the general direction of their destination.

Comment: Thanks @JenB for your comments. My intention was to first pick random xx% of turtles and send them for some while, and force them to come back after school. I will try to assign another attribute of their desired destination.

As you already commented, I see that my `lt` and `rt` doesn't seem to work at all. Decided to removed them.

Comment: see my answer with separated choosing a direction from moving toward it

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if you have separated identifying where to go from moving toward the destination, this is a cleaner version. It is not tested. I have scrapped the matrix since that was making you triple-handle choosing where to go. NetLogo doesn't have a 'choose case' type structure so nested `ifelse` is the way to go.

I also added some randomness to the direction since I think that was what you were trying to do with all the `heading` code.

```
patches-own [location] turtles-own [residency destination]

to setup
  clear-all

  ask patches [
    if pxcor >= 0 and pycor >= 0 [set pcolor black + 0 set location "ne" ]
    if pxcor <  0 and pycor >= 0 [set pcolor black + 1 set location "nw" ]
    if pxcor <  0 and pycor <  0 [set pcolor black + 2 set location "sw" ]
    if pxcor >= 0 and pycor <  0 [set pcolor black + 3 set location "se" ]
  ]

  ask n-of 40 patches
  [ sprout 1
    [ set shape "person student"
      set heading random 360
      set residency [location] of patch-here
      if residency = "nw" [set color yellow + 2]
      choose-destination
    ]
  ]

reset-ticks
end

to go
  ifelse(ticks mod 240 <= 120)[move-out][come-home]
  tick
end

to choose-destination
  ask turtles with [residency = "nw"]
  [ let myrandom random-float 1
    ifelse myrandom <= 0.5 [ set destination "nw" ] [
    ifelse myrandom <= 0.8 [ set destination "ne" ] [
    ifelse myrandom <= 0.9 [ set destination "sw" ] [
        set destination "se" ]]]
   ; similar code for each residency
end

to move-out
  ask turtles with [destination != location]
  [ face min-one-of patches with [location = destination][distance myself]
    set heading heading + 10 - random 20
    forward 1   ]
end

to come-home
; code more like revised move-out
end
```