# What is the most appropriate way to include randomness in the movement - NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

First, let me describe what I am doing and why I am asking this question.

I have 74 cities included in the model and I want to simulate movement between them. I have an OD probability matrix where rows are origins and columns are destinations. Matrix looks like this:

```
    0      1 ..... 73
----------------------
0  |0.5   0.1 .... 0.0
...| . . ..   . .
73 | 0.1  0.2  .. 0.3
```

Please note: if we look at the first row, that means that an agent from the city with index 0 has the probability to stay in it 0.5, to move to the city with idx=1 0.1 and so on.. What I want to do is to on the best statistically speaking way distribute agents' destination. For the agents which origin is city 0 I want to stay approximately 50% of agents (not exact 50%), but also I want to give some chance to the cities that have 0% probability, like pair 0-73.
I already coded the randomness according to the answer to this question: [Netlogo: How can send agents from "area x" to "area y" using an O/D matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449329/netlogo-how-can-send-agents-from-area-x-to-area-y-using-an-o-d-matrix)
But the answer for me in this question is not logical, concretely this part:

```
 ask turtles with [residency = "nw"]
 [ let myrandom random-float 1
  ifelse myrandom <= 0.5 [ set destination "nw" ] [
   ifelse myrandom <= 0.8 [ set destination "ne" ] [
   ifelse myrandom <= 0.0 [ set destination "sw" ] [
       set destination "se" ]]]
```

If I understood well, myrandom would take a value in the range 0-1 and then it would go to check one by one condition whether its' value is smaller or equal than this constant values.
In that sense, myrandom wound never get to the "sw" part (0 would always be smaller than 0.5) and there is more chance to get the "nw" part where probability is 0.5 than the "ne" part where the probability is higher-0.8. And only because it's not listed first. I am no sure that this is the right way to go, and also I am not sure which is (I can't sort my probabilities because their position represents city-id(see below)). Or I understood wrong?

Here is presented the part of my code. I imported the matrix without the headings/cities ID because they are equivalent to NetLogo indexing.  The cities with ID are already imported into the model. Also, in each point/city I created the corresponding number of agents that I read for each city from the CSV file. During the creation of the agents, I use the row from the matrix that corresponds to the current city/origin and go through the probabilities as JenB did in his answer above.

```
breed [city cities]
breed [inhabitant inhabitants]


;; part of the setup
;; open the csv file that contains population per city
file-open path                                             
while [ not file-at-end? ] [
 let data csv:from-row file-read-line                  
 let city-id item 0 data
 let population item 1 data

 to add-inhabitants
 create-inhabitants population [
   set city-home one-of cities with [id = city-id] ;; set the origin
   move-to city-home
   set-destination(city-id)  ;; for this origin chose the destination
  ]
]


 to set-destination [row]  ;; row from the matrix which represent the movement from the current city/origin to other cities
 let row-probabilities matrix:get-row od-matrix row  ;; use the row that correspondents to the city
 let random-value random-float 1
 let i 0                                   ;; index counter
 foreach  row-probabilities [              ;; for each probability in row
  p ->
 
if random-value <= p                       ;; this part is coded as in the JenB's answer
   [ 
      set destination one-of cities with [id = i] ;; i is column index which is actually index of destination city
      stop ;; if you set city -> stop
]
if i = 73 [set destination one-of cities with [id = i] 
           stop] ;; the last city -> there is no more option/reason to check
      
set i i + 1
]
 end
```

I know it's a little bit longer, but I wanted to explain clearly. Some guidelines and explanations would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question suggests that you don't understand what the code in that section is doing. This is the corrected code for that bit:

```
 ask turtles with [residency = "nw"]
 [ let myrandom random-float 1
   ifelse myrandom <= 0.5 [ set destination "nw" ] [
   ifelse myrandom <= 0.8 [ set destination "ne" ] [
   ifelse myrandom <= 0.9 [ set destination "sw" ] [
       set destination "se" ]]]
```

Yes, the first line in the block draws a random number in the range 0 to 1. Imagine that the draw gave 0.4. Then the first `ifelse` would be true and the destination would be set to "nw". Now imagine the draw was 0.6, then the first `ifelse` would be false and the code would go on to test the `else` part, which is true because 0.6 <= 0.8.

The code works because the initial draw is uniform. That is, 10% of the time (on average) it returns a number in the range 0 to 0.1, and 10% in the range 0.1 to 0.2 and so on. So 50% of the time it returns a number in the range 0 to 0.5, which returns true for the first line. 30% of the time it returns a number in the range 0.5 to 0.8, which is false for the first test and true for the second test. 10% of the time it returns a number in the range 0.8 to 0.9 and 10% of the time it returns a number in the range 0.9 to 1.

So breaking the interval with check points at 0.5, 0.8, 0.9 (and 1 for the remainder) gives you sections that are 0.5, 0.3 (=0.8-0.5), 0.1 (=0.9-0.8) and 0.1 (=1=0.9) in length. And a uniform random number will fall into those sections with probability distribution 50%, 30%, 10% and 10% of the draws.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understood as you explained, I just didn't realize that was the goal.. I thought that those numbers are probabilities and that's the thing that confused me, plus the zero that was in the now corrected line.. Do you have any thoughts regarding my problem? What would be the best way to increase stochasticity in those probabilities?

Comment: I think it would be appropriate to put the line `let random-value random-float 1` inside the loop, but not the good enough. Because first listed cities would always have the preferences than the cities that come after them. That's part that confusing me.

Comment: The random draw is already inside the loop. Each turtle (is that a city for you?) draws its own random number independently. And each `tick` (time step), those numbers are drawn again. It doesn't matter for this application, but the order that the cities do these actions is also random.

Comment: I have inhabitants independently from cities (different breeds). So in first while loop I create the agents in each city (read from csv file). During the creation and accordingly to origin (in which city turtles in that moment being created) I give them random numb which i compare in the foreach loop with the row that contains probabilities for agents' movement from that city to another. Those probabilities aren't sorted, they look as this [0.1 0.05 0.3..until 74. city]. And I am confused here about the most appropriate way to distributed agents. I explained my concerns in the second paragraph

Comment: I don't understand your problem. It doesn't matter whether the probabilities are sorted or not. They should add to 1 if they're probabilities, but you can do the same approach even if they add to some other number. So if you have weights like [0.5 0.8 0.3 1 0.2] then you would use `random-float 2.8` and the `ifelse` checks would be at 0.5, 1.3, 1.6 and 2.6.

Comment: Lets say that probabilities in one row are sorted like this: [0.3 0.2 0.5 0.0 0.2] (each row goes up to 1). I create a turtle and give it random value in the range 0-1 and then enter the loop and ask if the given-probability <= value from the row with i-th index. Because of this order, no-one will get opportunity to get second city in the list as their destination. Because each value that is smaller than 0.2 would always be smaller than a first value: 0.3 and that's the catch.

Comment: I know that I can ask turtles according to this p x n (probability x number_of_turtles from the city) and then set their destination. But I want to include more randomness in this. Because I want to give the opportunity to the cities that have p=0.0

Comment: That's not the catch - that's your misunderstanding of my comment in the line immediately before the 'catch' comment. If your probability values are [0.3 0.2 0.5 0.0 0.2], then your ifelse values are 0.3, 0.5, 1 and you are drawing from the range 0 to 1.2. For example the 0.5 is the SUM of all the values to that point (0.3 + 0.2) and 1.2 is the sum of ALL the values. The small chance to the 0 probability is easiest done by a separate random draw with a small chance of randomly picking any city.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. The sum part I missed.  And btw for each row sum is one, I just put the random numbers for example. 
Thank you for your patient and time!
I don't know if you want to update your answer, it's up to you. I accepted it. :)